# How common is faculty members changing jobs in the US?

Tags: professorship, university

Faculty members switch between universities for many reasons, but how often does this happen? Has there been any study/report on the frequency of job shifts and resignations in academia, especially in the US?

Comment: I don't know if there's a report, but faculty movement is quite common. Often faculty will take a leave of absence instead of resigning, and this can drag for a while .

Answer (score 3):

The frequency with which faculty members switch departments varies by field. For example, it happens much more frequently in Economics than in Computer Science. I remember lunch-time discussions proposing an informal study aimed at testing the hypothesis that this difference in mobility was partially responsible for the income gap between econ and CS (economists make substantially more money), but looking for it now, I can't find it. Maybe it was never written up...

Comment: Also, it really depends on the health of the field.  CS faculty were much more mobile (and salaries increased accordingly) during the .com bubble than they are now.